# echoing array in forms

Tags: php

please i am trying to update a form , but it only updates the last row , i have tried to echo the post values sent(item[Pidno] and item[Pquantity] ) as array but it comes back with just the last row item[Pquantity] update , and it does not return the item[Pidno], where am i going wrong

```
 <?
$pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac");
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th> SHOP NAME</th><th> PRODUCT NAME</th><th>
PRODUCT SIZE</th><th> PRODUCT COLOUR</th><th> PRODUCT QUANTITY</th><th>
PRICE</th><th> </th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)){?>
<form action='updatepplac.php' method='Post' class='slistbar'>
<?echo "<tr><td>" .$row['Sname'] ."</td><td>" .$row['Pname'] ."</td><td>" .$row['Psize'] ."</td><td>" .$row['Pcolour'] ."</td><td>" ."<input type='text' name='item[Pquantity]' id='Pquantity' value='{$row['Pquantity']}' >" ."</td><td>" .$row['Price'] ."</td><td>" ?>
<a href="deleteproduct.php?del=<?php echo $row['Pidno'];?>">delete</a></td></tr>
<input type='hidden' name='item[Pidno]' id='Pidno' value='<?php echo $row['Pidno']; ?>' ><?php }
// table closing tag
?>
```

the update script

```
 $submit = $_POST['submit'];
        //$rowdelete = $_GET['del'];
        $nPquantity = $_POST['item'];
        foreach($nPquantity as $Pquantitys){
list($pidno, $Pquantity) = $Pquantitys;
        echo "$Pquantitys";
        //echo "$rowdelete";
         //echo "$pidno";
          //echo "$Pquantity";
        die();
```

Comment: Check your input with echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";

Comment: Your HTML tags are in the wrong places. You do not want a new `<form>` element on every iteration, and a `<form>` is not valid as a direct child of a `<table>`. This is likely to be the source of your problem, as when you click the submit button that I presume is being output after the loop, it will only submit the data in the last `<form>`. To fix this, move the `<form action='updatepplac.php' method='Post' class='slistbar'>` to the first line. You also need to change `name="item[Pidno]"` to `name="item[Pidno][]"` to collect all the data as an array

Comment: when you mean to the first line are you saying above

Comment: $pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac");

Comment: i have adjusted the code, it is echoing all the array for the pidno, but not for the pquantity                                          from name='item[Pidno]'  to name='item[Pidno][]'

Answer (score 1):

Following the changes from my comment above, here is how I would write your code:

```
<?php

  // Output start of table and form
  echo "
    <form action='updatepplac.php' method='Post' class='slistbar'>
    <table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <th>SHOP NAME</th>
        <th>PRODUCT NAME</th>
        <th>PRODUCT SIZE</th>
        <th>PRODUCT COLOUR</th>
        <th>PRODUCT QUANTITY</th>
        <th>PRICE</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>";

  // Get DB results and loop, outputting table rows with counter
  $pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac") or die(mysql_error());
  for ($i = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult); $i++) {
    echo "
      <tr>
        <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Sname'])."</td>
        <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Pname'])."</td>
        <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Psize'])."</td>
        <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Pcolour'])."</td>
        <td>
          <input type='text' name='item[$i][Pquantity]' id='Pquantity' value='".htmlspecialchars($row['Pquantity'])."' />
          <input type='hidden' name='item[$i][Pidno]' id='Pidno' value='".htmlspecialchars($row['Pidno'])."' />
        </td>
        <td>".htmlspecialchars($row['Price'])."</td>
        <td><a href='deleteproduct.php?del=".htmlspecialchars($row['Pidno'])."'>delete</a></td>
      </tr>";
  }

  // Close table and form
  echo "
    </table>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>";

?>
```

Then after the form has been submitted, you can loop the submitted data like this:

```
<?php

  $items = $_POST['item'];

  foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    echo "Item $key: Pquantity={$item['Pquantity']}; Pidno={$item['Pidno']}<br>\n";
  }
```

Comment: thanks it worked, i should be able to work on the update part now.

Comment: @david, please i am have a syntax error by the update command

Comment: @user1158373 Please update you question with the code you are having a problem with

Answer (score 0):

This is always the same in your form, so the only the last Pidno will be in $_POST[item]

```
name='item[Pidno]'
```

Do as you do later:

```
name='item[<?php echo $row['Pidno']; ?>]'
```